# Error:Cursor state not valid when when execute storeprodure in java JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, rpgle

Im trying to return a resultset from external store procedure who call a RPG program  but  return this error.

```
18:12:17,457 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: Cursor state not valid.
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR] at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:408)
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:1590)
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:342)
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at pe.diners.gespagos.model.dao.jdbc.genericoDaoJdbc.obtenerListaConsumo(genericoDaoJdbc.java:148)
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at pe.diners.gespagos.model.facade.GesPagosFacadeBean.obtenerListaConsumo(GesPagosFacadeBean.java:168)
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
18:12:17,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
```

My code is:

```
Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    ResultSet rs= null;
    List<Consumo> dto = null;
    StringBuffer sbSQL = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        logger.info("Inicio-->SP131119");
        conn = ResourceManager.getConnection(JNDIContext.JNDI_DATASOURCE_GESPAGOS);
        String esquema = FrameworkParameters.getValue(GesPagosConstant.ESQUEMA_RPG);
        sbSQL.append("{CALL ").append(esquema);
        sbSQL.append(".").append(GesPagosConstant.SP_LIST_CONSUMOS).append("(?,?,?,?)}");
        cs = conn.prepareCall(sbSQL.toString());            
        System.out.println(sbSQL.toString());
        cs.setString(1, opcion);
        cs.setString(2, tarjeta);
        cs.setString(3, sisTrab);
        cs.setString(4, tipCta);        

//              rs = cs.getResultSet() ;
//          }

//          Statement stmnt =    conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
////            rs = stmnt.executeQuery("CALL WOOLB3.IR131119   ('01','36239741118139','04','022001')");
//           Boolean b= stmnt.execute("CALL WOOLB3.IR131119 ('01','36239741118139','04','022001')");
            System.out.println(cs.toString());
rs = cs.executeQuery();
//           System.out.println(b);
//           rs = stmnt.getResultSet();

if(rs != null){ 
    dto = new ArrayList<Consumo>();
    while(rs.next()){*}
```

If I use callablestatement.execute(), cs.getResultset return null.

someone could help me, please??

Comment: What is the definition of the stored procedure?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are defining the result set in the RPG program.